Why I don't see the OptimizerStatsUsage in the execution plan
SQL Server 2017 introduces a very helpful enhancement to the showplan to see which statistics were used to generate a plan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/archive/blogs/sql_server_team/sql-server-2017-showplan-enhancements
However, I can't find it in my execution plan.
I have the following query on the StackOverflow database:
Use StackOverflow2010;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempPosts;
CREATE TABLE #tempPosts(
    Id int
)

INSERT INTO #tempPosts
SELECT ID FROM dbo.Posts
WHERE OwnerUserId = 26837

SELECT Title, u.DisplayName, pt.Type FROM dbo.Posts p
INNER JOIN #tempPosts temp
ON p.Id = temp.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Users u
ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.PostTypes pt
ON p.PostTypeId = pt.Id
OPTION(RECOMPILE)

I turned on the Include Actual Execution Plan to capture the plan and could not find OptimizerStatsUsage field in the plan:

What could be the reason for OptimizerStatsUsage not showing up in my execution plan? Is there any additional configuration or step needed to see this property?
Thank you for any insights!

the stackoverflow2010 database might be set to lower version of compatibility level. During my test it is set to 100 which is 2008. You either need to change the database compatibility level to atleast 2014(120) OR on your query you can use the query optimizer hint like this:
SELECT Title, u.DisplayName, pt.Type FROM dbo.Posts p
INNER JOIN #tempPosts temp
ON p.Id = temp.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Users u
ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.PostTypes pt
ON p.PostTypeId = pt.Id
OPTION(RECOMPILE, USE HINT('QUERY_OPTIMIZER_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL_120')) /* query optimizer hint 120 or higher */

i initially thought this could be due to a lower version of SSMS but using 18.11.1 (older version) still works when change the compatibility level of database or using query optimizer hint.
Then the OptimizerStatsUsage will show up.
Also from your screenshot, the CardinalityEstimationModelVersion was 70 (using old version).

Thank you so much for your answer! I used the query hint, and it worked. However, I am not quite sure why it switched to using the 70 CardinalityEstimationModelVersion. Apparently, when I checked the database compatibility level in the sys.databases, it showed the table is compatibility level 150. Any insight about this would be greatly appreciated!

sys.databases looks fine to me. it shows compat level 100. maybe you just need to close the query tab you are working on and create a new tab.
